# How to remove a transport route through Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the [Phoenix Chat Room Example](https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example) and am having some problems with routing.

Inside the `user_socket.ex` file:

```
defmodule Chat.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  channel "rooms:*", Chat.RoomChannel

  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket

  def connect(_params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def id(_socket), do: nil
end
```

The problem I have is under the [`transport`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Socket.html#transport/3) configuration.

`transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.Websocket`

Setting up a transport is basically like a directory. To connect through this socket, the client must have `/websocket` at the end of their `URL`. I am trying to gracefully remove that. I'm trying to get my websocket server to be accessed by `server:port`, with no directory requirements.

---

I found that the `Chat.UserSocket` module is called from `lib/chat/endpoint.ex`:

`socket "/Balancer", Chat.UserSocket`

Which this `socket` is also adding another required directory. So, to connect to the `websocket` server, you would need to append `/Balancer/websocket` to the URL. I am trying to remove that requirement. I could shorten the words, and use `B/W`, but that just seems unintuitive. Also, I'm fairly new to Elixir/Phoenix so I apologize for this sloppy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to have a separate path for your websockets. There are couple of reasons why it is better to use standard 80 or 443 ports [Shall I use WebSocket on ports other than 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522857/shall-i-use-websocket-on-ports-other-than-80)

By default socket constructor in java script adds the `websocket` part, but you can easily assign whatever you want like this:

```
socket.endPoint = "/ws"
```

In the endpoint you can then match on root:

```
socket "/", Chat.UserSocket
```

and in the user socket you need to use:

```
transport :ws, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
```

It is totally possible to use "/" without any other paths as a root for your websocket on the JS side, but if you try it in this chat example, you will see that the request matches on `Chat.PageController.index`. You could try then with empty atom for transport `:""`, but it is a little hacky and may not work, so I would stick to the `/ws` path.