# AJAX and WebSocket Responses Comingled

Tags: ajax, tomcat, websocket

I am streaming data from a Tomcat server through a WebSocket to the browser.

I am also making several AJAX calls to the Tomcat server.

I have definite log proof that the AJAX response data is being comingled into the WebSocket.  Is there a bug on Tomcat?

Both the AJAX calls and the WebSocket are running on the same port (8080 defined in the server.xml).  According to another StackOverflow post, running them both on the same port is a good idea:  [Shall I use WebSocket on ports other than 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522857/shall-i-use-websocket-on-ports-other-than-80)

Comment: Different protocols involved - wss/https. Protocol modules in tomcat cannot intersperse responses. Tomcat endpoint handlers doing so would mean bugs showing up in all deployments. I use tomcat 8 and don’t see such issues. Please post your log proof to the tomcat users thread for further help.

Comment: Apologies.  The data is not being comingled; the bad data just looked like it was from an AJAX call.  Anyone who thinks they have this problem should examine their data more closely.