# Web sockets and Rest API in same Tomcat based application

Tags: rest, tomcat, websocket, java-websocket

I have read up on web sockets providing full duplex connections over TCP which can be used in scenarios where long polling was used to get live updates to client from server. Now I have a Tomcat based application which serves multiple REST based web service response, and I want couple of API's to be implemented using web sockets say to render dashboard with latest data where multiple users are working on them concurrently, is that possible ? My concern here was even if the connection was upgraded to TCP from HTTP wouldn't web socket require a separate port to run than the default Tomcat port 8080. In that case should I house the Web Socket based endpoints separate to the Tomcat based application already running. Please do correct me if any of the above is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of month ago, I wrote a small Spring Boot webapp with embedded Tomcat that provides both, REST endpoints and websocket support, and both via the same port. So, yes that works... if you wanna sneak a peek: https://github.com/tommybrettschneider/pinterest-boot

Besides that, this post should also clarify things:

[Shall I use WebSocket on ports other than 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522857/shall-i-use-websocket-on-ports-other-than-80)

Comment: Can you please give a brief explanation how that would work on the same port. Thanks in advance.